# Pandas, filter column for > date

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to filter on column assessed date like so:

`netnewprocess = netnewprocess[(netnewprocess['AssessedDate'] > assessdateprev)]`

my `assessdateprev` = `8/31/2021 00:00`

The filter seems to work on most values but I still see items before Aug 31 in the column. The top half of the results below are correct, and bottom half shouldnt be there. Anything I can do to fix this?

```
9       9/15/2020 1:40:27 PM
136     9/14/2020 4:07:19 PM
146     9/21/2020 4:28:59 PM
185     9/18/2020 2:20:15 PM
200      9/8/2020 9:59:22 AM
        
1687     8/6/2021 8:47:07 AM
1757     8/6/2021 4:59:01 PM
1785     8/5/2021 9:42:14 AM
1787     8/5/2021 9:40:51 AM
1810     8/6/2021 2:00:58 PM
```

Comment: check the data type of your column, `df.dtypes`, if your column does not have datetime or similar dtype, especially if it is string, the error can happen

Comment: `assessdataprev` is a `str` and `AssessedDate` is an object.

Comment: There are few different ways to handle this. Have you tried string methods to chop the time part before filtering?  i.e.  choose a number n so that df[date_colmn].apply(lambda x: x[:n]) returns mm/dd/yyyy then try filtering out anything before 08/31/2021.. I will try to add a proper answer once I have more time sorry.

Comment: If your first half of sample data is in year 2020, they shouldn't appear in the final result at all (since they are earlier than `8/31/2021 00:00`) .  I've changed all dates to 2021 for testing in my solution.

Comment: @SeaBean , sorry, didnt even realize that. You are correct.

Comment: @Jonnyboi yeah, if those are strings, then `8/6/2021` is bigger than `8/31/2021` as it compares the char, convert it to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime()` like in the answer

Comment: @Jonnyboi You got the September 2020 entries also extracted when compared >  `8/31/2021 00:00`.  This is owing to the same reason, the string value of the first character '9' is larger than string value of first character '8' in `assessdateprev`.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your column `AssessedDate` and constant `assessdateprev` are of string type rather than datetime type, your existing code actually filters by string comparison and gave the wrong result.

It is because the string `8/6/2021 8:47:07 AM` when compared with the other string `8/31/2021 00:00`, the string comparison result will be `8/6/2021 8:47:07 AM` > `8/31/2021 00:00` since when compared character by character, '6' on the left is larger than '3' on the right.

To solve the problem, you have to convert both the column and the date string constant to datetime format before comparison:

You can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with supplying the correct format string in the `format=` parameter:

1. Use `pd.to_datetime(netnewprocess['AssessedDate'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')` in place of `netnewprocess['AssessedDate']`, and
2. Use `pd.to_datetime('8/31/2021 00:00', format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')` in place of `assessdateprev`

to change your code to:

```
netnewprocess = netnewprocess[(pd.to_datetime(netnewprocess['AssessedDate'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p') > pd.to_datetime('8/31/2021 00:00', format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))]
```

You may find the codes above also works without supplying the format strings.  However, there's 2 advantages doing this: (1) avoid ambiguity whether `8/6/2021` is Aug 6 or Jun 8; (2) possibly speed up the datetime format conversion by saving internal processing time at inferring the actual date format.

**Result:**

(replaced your sample data with all dates in year 2021, instead of the first half in 2020)

```
print(netnewprocess)

             AssessedDate
9    9/15/2021 1:40:27 PM
136  9/14/2021 4:07:19 PM
146  9/21/2021 4:28:59 PM
185  9/18/2021 2:20:15 PM
200   9/8/2021 9:59:22 AM
```

Or, better still, if you are fine to change the format of the column and the date string constant to datetime format, you can use:

```
# convert to datetime first
netnewprocess['AssessedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(netnewprocess['AssessedDate'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
assessdateprev = pd.to_datetime('8/31/2021 00:00', format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

# Then, you can use your code
netnewprocess = netnewprocess[(netnewprocess['AssessedDate'] > assessdateprev)]
```